# how to define an additional source directory in maven-apt-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

We have some of our JPA entities generated in target/java directory during maven goal "generate". But not all of them are generated, as some of them are in our src/main/java directory. Is there any way to configure the plugin to specify more than one source directory?

I have tried with `<additionalSourceRoots>target/java<additionalSourceRoots>` but it does not work. I halve also tried to add target/java but then this is the only directory that is processed to the other JPA entities that are in the main code that are not generated are not processed.

I know I could try a workaround trying to copy the generated sources to another directory and putting there the other entities as well, but I am wondering if there is a "clean" solution for this.

*EDITED*

After Andrey answer I have tried this as well, but still does not work. maven-apt-plugin cannot see the classes generated classes located in target/java. I have tried with `<additionalSourceRoots>` with different syntax without any luck.. :(

```xml
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <sources>
                    <source>target/java</source>                        
                  </sources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>                   
                <goal>process</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <additionalSourceRoots>
                    <additionalSourceRoot>target/java</additionalSourceRoot>
                </additionalSourceRoots>                    
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maven [build helper pligin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) will do the job.

Then just add more source roots in maven-apt-plugin with "additionalSourceRoots" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Our problem was that we had some classes in **directory1** and **directory2** that was used by the classes in **directory3**. The classes in **directory3** was the classes with JPA annotations. We also found that it is important to put the directory with JPA annotated classes as the last directory, otherwise there was no classes generated by the apt plugin.

Surprisingly enough I tried to add additional sourceDirectory tags and it worked for me:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>__directory1__</sourceDirectory>
                    <sourceDirectory>__directory2__</sourceDirectory>
                    <sourceDirectory>__directory3__</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                    <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```